# Error 1064 in SQL code generated by MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have one little problem with creating my first tables in MySQL Workbench. When I create two tables and go through the Forward Engineering Progress I get the message stated below:

> Executing SQL script in server
>       ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>       check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version 
>       for the right syntax to use near
>         'INDEX `fk_person_has_user_person_idx` (`person_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
>         CONSTRAINT' at line 8

SQL Code:

```
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `customers`.`person_has_user`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers`.`person_has_user` (
          `person_ID` INT NOT NULL,
          `user_person_ID` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`person_ID`, `user_person_ID`),
          INDEX `fk_person_has_user_user1_idx` (`user_person_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
          INDEX `fk_person_has_user_person_idx` (`person_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_person_has_user_person`
            FOREIGN KEY (`person_ID`)
            REFERENCES `customers`.`person` (`ID`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_person_has_user_user1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`user_person_ID`)
            REFERENCES `customers`.`user` (`person_ID`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? The `VISIBLE` keyword is not available in older versions. Use the query `SELECT VERSION();` to find out what version you're running.

Comment: removing the VISIBLE keyword works for me. Thanks mate!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ed Cottrell is correct. This is a version mismatch between your MySQL server version and your MySQL Workbench settings.

1. Do `SELECT VERSION();` to get your server to tell you its version.
2. In Workbench, do Edit / Preferences / Modeling > MySQL, and set the **Default Target MySQL Version** to your server version.

Then Workbench will generate code suitable for the server you actually use.

This error is quite likely to happen for new users;  newly downloaded Workbench software has the default set to MySQL 8, but many servers out there in the world are not on version 8 (yet).

Comment: MySQL used to be so simple; sigh.